# Getting noUiSlider working with Reagent?

Tags: clojurescript, nouislider, reagent

I'm trying to get [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) to work with [reagent](https://reagent-project.github.io/) (especially [this](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-dates) example) but I fail to do so. I've downloaded the 9.2.0 version of the javascript and css which I import from my HTML (I've verified that it's downloaded) and my extern file looks like this (and it's used in Leiningen: `:externs [..., "nouislider_extern.js"]`):

```
var noUiSlider = {};

noUiSlider.create = function(node, params){};

noUiSlider.destroy = function() {};

noUiSlider.on = function(event, cb) {};

noUiSlider.get = function() {};

noUiSlider.set = function(val) {};
```

My component is defined like this:

```
(defn- create-slider! [start step min max node]
  (js/noUiSlider.create
    node
    (js-obj
      "start" start
      ;"connect" connect
      "step" step
      "range" (js-obj "min" min
                      "max" max))))

(defn- home-render []
  [:div {:id "slider-date"}])


(defn nouislider-comp
  []
  (fn []
    (reagent/create-class {:reagent-render      home-render
                           :component-did-mount (partial create-slider!
                                                         (clj->js [(.getTime (js/Date. "2011")), (.getTime (js/Date. "2015"))])
                                                         7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                                                         (.getTime (js/Date. "2010"))
                                                         (.getTime (js/Date. "2010")))})))
```

But when `create-slider!` is called it throws an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined
    at Function.myapp$components$nouislidercomp$create_slider_BANG_ (date_slider_range.cljs:36)
    at Function.cljs.core.apply.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$5 (core.cljs:3706)
    at Constructor.G__9299__delegate (core.cljs:4099)
    at Constructor.G__9299 (core.cljs:4099)
    at Constructor.reagent$impl$component$custom_wrapper_$_componentDidMount [as componentDidMount] (component.cljs:188)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.invokeComponentDidMountWithTimer (react.inc.js:5739)
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (react.inc.js:839)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (react.inc.js:13064)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (react.inc.js:16276)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (react.inc.js:16223)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have added `nouislider.js` to your html?

Comment: Well afaict, at least I see in Chrome that the script is downloaded from the server correctly

Comment: That's strange, because your example works for me (after fixing some syntax errors). Are you compiling it in :advanced mode or just debugging it with figwheel and no optimization?

Comment: Oh, really? That's interesting. I'll try to investigate it more tomorrow. Thanks for helping out so far.

Comment: I've only tried it with figwheel without optimizations so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several problems with my code above (besides obvious cut and paste errors). The error I stated in my question (`Uncaught ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined`) was due to caching. There were other problems as well such as not supplying `create-slider!` with a dom node. So for reference here's a working example:

```
(defn- create-slider! [start step min max node]
  (js/noUiSlider.create
    node
    (js-obj
      "start" start
      "step" step
      "range" (js-obj "min" min
                      "max" max))))

(defn home-render []
  [:div {:id "slider-date"}])

(defn date-slider-range-comp
  []
  (fn []
    (reagent/create-class {:reagent-render      home-render
                           :component-did-mount (fn [node]
                                                  (create-slider!
                                                    (clj->js [(.getTime (js/Date. "2011")) (.getTime (js/Date. "2015"))])
                                                    (* 7 24 60 60 1000)
                                                    (.getTime (js/Date. "2010"))
                                                    (.getTime (js/Date. "2017"))
                                                    (reagent/dom-node node)))})))
```